# How can I run "ack" in bash and save the output to a file?

Tags: bash, grep, ack

I have the following test.txt file with two lines

```
keyword 1, 2010-10-01 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
keyword 2, 2010-10-01 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

and would like to [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) for `keyword1` and `keyword2`. I call this script

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUTPATH=$1"/"
JOB=$2
ID="_"$3".csv"

for keyword in "${@:4}"
do
        trKeyWord=$(echo "$keyword" | sed 's/ //g')
        ack \""$keyword"\" $JOB > $OUTPUTPATH$trKeyWord$BSLD_ID
done
```

via

```
bash script.sh /home/username/ test.txt test "keyword 1" "keyword 2"
```

The ouput files `keyword1_test.csv`, `keyword2_test.csv` are created but they are empty! The problem must be how I am using `ack \""$keyword"\" $JOB` because just running this command gives an empty result.

Comment: Why do you backslash the outer double quotes?

Comment: If I just use "$keyword" it will execute `ack keyword 1 test.txt` but I want `ack "keyword 1" test.txt`

Comment: @tenticon No, that's wrong.

Comment: Your quotes in the first three lines are kind of backwards. If anything, you want to quote the variables, not the fixed strings: `OUTPUTPATH="$1"/; JOB="$2"; ID=_"$3".csv`. But you should use lowercase variable names; ALL_UPPERCASE variables are for the system.

Comment: Also, you can remove a space with `${keyword/ }`, no need for an external command.

Comment: @choroba Or `trKeyWord="${keyword// }"` to remove all spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Okay guys, this is the final (working) answer:

```
outputpath="$1"/
job="$2"
id=_"$3".csv
for keyword in "${@:4}"
do
  trKeyWord=${keyword// }
  ack "$keyword" $job > $outputpath$trKeyWord$id
done
```

Comment: Woops, it appears that my answer was wrong and that this one is correct, congrats on the fix.

Comment: Be sure to quote your variables.  If, say, `outputpath` was `my output dir` your redirection wouldn't work the way you want.  Similar concerns for the `job` and the other variables as well